# replace i5 with i7 cpu in mid2012 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro

is it possible to change my i5 iwy bridge CPU with an i7 one in my mid 2012 mbp?
My mbp is a non retina model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The CPU is welded on the motherboard. You can't replace it with your own.

The only upgrade you can do on your own is changing RAM, hard drive, and replacing optical drive with a second hard drive, if you need.

Comment: Unless you are very good with a soldering iron. Assuming they are pin-compatible chips.

Comment: Even if you are an experienced technician, such task is hardly possible.

Comment: Haha, I want to see ANYONE desoldering a CPU using a soldering iron :D

Comment: okay, thanks for the ansver :) Could you suggest me an optical drive replacement modul that can hold ssd?

Comment: You can go to any online store (amazon, ebay etc) and search hard drive caddy tray, and buy the one whose size matches yours.